# How to bind dropdown list with collection in adobe CQ5..?

Tags: drop-down-menu, adobe, selection, aem

i'm new in Adobe CQ5, i'm developing a training project, here my requirement for binding a Dropdown list using Dialog, there author can add multiple item, and these item should be display in dropdown list, so how to do this,
 i create a component with dialog
 i assigned field what i need & also give an property as text field i'm able to bind it but i want to use them as collection

my code for component.jsp is:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator,com.day.text.Text,com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page,com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Image,com.day.cq.commons.Doctype" %>


 <div class="main-container">
 <div class="hero-dropdown-container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1" type="button" class="menu-black-arrow btn btn-default status dropdown-toggle"><%= properties.get("itemText") %></button>
          <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href='<%= properties.get("itemValue") %>'><%= properties.get("itemText") %></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><%= properties.get("itemValue") %></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the multiple values added from dialog goes to jcr ?

Comment: yes i know, but not able to make it happen

Comment: Add more details to the question like your dialog box code along with the screenshot of content node etc.

Comment: screen shot for crxde:
http://screencast.com/t/TpEvc8yZhbF

screen shot for dropdownlist:

http://screencast.com/t/JZD3cJzSfuT

screen shot for design dialog in browser:  
http://screencast.com/t/P5EjEUWsJM3u

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to associate itemText and itemValue the required xtype would be [compositefield](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/output/CQ.Ext.form.CompositeField.html). But it doesn't work for multiple rows. The [multifield](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/output/CQ.form.MultiField.html) xtype that's supposed to work with multiple rows doesn't work with a compositefield. What you will have to do is write a multi-compositefield.

Method to do this well documented on stackoverflow and adobe forums , few links :

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-xtype.html

[Multifield component issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290908/multifield-component-issue/26294172#26294172)

However there are few open source solutions for this :

http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/widgets.html#multi-field-panel-since-150

https://github.com/Citytechinc/multicomposite-addon

Comment: hi @Sharath i used multifield for this but issue only with getting value, how to get values for particular text for dropdown items

Comment: @Amitavin multifield does not work with multiple values

Comment: i also tried with comositfield that time dialog is not dispaying

Comment: what xtype is most suiatble for dropdown list collection

Comment: @Amitavin, You can download some demo from the below link of custommultified & try http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2013/09/aem-cq-56-multifield-panel.html